# How to use google app engine with ajax (json)?

Tags: google-app-engine

How to use google app engine with ajax (json)?

Now I have this but I got this error:

```
raise ValueError(&quot;No JSON object could be decoded&quot;)
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded


from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import simplejson as json

class AjaxHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        args = json.loads(self.request.body)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        self.response.out.write('Hello, webapp World!')





application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/AJAX', AjaxHandler)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and javascript + jquery:

```
var Server = function() {
};
Server.prototype = {
    init: function(ajaxTargetUrl) {
        this.ajaxTargetUrl = ajaxTargetUrl;
    },
    request: function(service, data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.ajaxTargetUrl,
            context: document.body,
            success: function(data) {
                $('body').append('<p>'+data+'</p>');
            },
            error: function(){
                $('body').append('<p>error</p>');
            },
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
};

var APP = ( function() {
    var server = new Server();
    server.init('http://localhost:9999/AJAX');
    server.request('questions.all', {test:'hey', y:99});
}());
```

my self.request.body = str: test=hey&y=99

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. as long as I know `self.request.body` wouldn't return anything. There's no argument named 'body' in your query-string, but I might be wrong. So, if it returns something, this something is a STRING. So `simplejson.dumps()` cannot turn it into a valid JSON.

   If you need a 'list' of all arguments you have sent to the server, use `self.request.arguments()`
2. `self.response.out.write('Hello, webapp World!')` do not send a valid JSON back to client. It sends a *string* with "application/json" header instead of "plain/text". Try to create a python dictionary. For example:

   `my_response = {'ajax_resp':'Hello, webapp World!'}

   json = json.dumps(my_resposne)`

   and then

   `self.response.headers.add_header('content-type', 'application/json', charset='utf-8')

   self.response.out.write(json)`
3. On the client side I would suggest you to use console.log() (debugging tool) for testing your responses.

   you can just try:

   `$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/AJAX', // or your absolute-path
      data : name=totty&age=20,
      dataType : 'json',
      success : function(resp) 
                {
                console.info("Ajax Response is there.....");
                console.log(resp);
                }
      });`

Comment: xD totty@20 xDD thanks man! now I get it, but when I serialize back data from gae to js i got some problems at datetime variables. I have models in gae that i need to send to the client, how do i do? best practice

Comment: If my post helped you, you can accept the answer. Yes! reputation is everything!
That's way i have suggested to use console.log() on client-side. If gae returns an error you can see it as response text of an ajax call. Not the best practice, I know, but it works. Anyway, you should post the errors (datetime) u get for further help.

Comment: "self.request.body" in App Engine its not a parameter in the request (that would be "self.request.get('body')" ). It refers to the body of the HTTP request.

Comment: is the self.response.headers.add_header('content-type', 'application/json', charset='utf-8') required?

Comment: @Robert you are right but still in GAE documentation this is the example given: args = simplejson.loads(self.request.body)

Comment: @JimmyKane : simplejson.loads(self.request.body) is correct. It takes the http request body, assume that is formatted as json, and transform it to a json object. What I was trying to say is that 'body' in this case is the request http body and not an arbitrary parameter in the request..

Answer (score 3):

Your JavaScript is not sending JSON data to App Engine (`test=hey&y=99` is a urlencoded string).  Your App Engine page is not returning JSON data (`Hello, webapp World!` will just be received as a naked string).