# 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta' on Django Serializer

Tags: json, django, django-queryset, django-serializer

```
def display_home(request):
    from datetime import *
    now=datetime.today()
    print 'Month is %s'%now.month

events=Event.objects.filter(e_date__year=datetime.today().year).filter(e_date__month=datetime.today().month,e_status=1).values('e_name','e_date')
return render_to_response("SecureVirtualElection/home.html",{'events': serializers.serialize("json",events, fields=('e_name','e_date'))},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

...
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
events = (
    Event.objects.filter(e_date__year=datetime.today().year)
    .filter(e_date__month=datetime.today().month, e_status=1)
    .only("e_name", "e_date")
)
```

Serializer waits for normal queryset, not `ValuesQuerySet` (which is returned by `values`). If you want to query only certain fileds, use `only.`

Comment: What would happen if I want to get data from multiple tables, in that case I would have to use 'values', and I come back to square one.

Comment: Note: You still have to use the fields parameter when serializing, to restrict the output to certain fields