# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django

Got code

```
shops = Shop.objects.filter(id__in=list(set(shop_ids))).all()
shop_list = []
for s in shops.only():
    shop_list.append({
        'id': s.id,
        'name': s.name,
        'preview': s.preview,
    })

response_data['shop'] = serializers.serialize('json', shop_list)

return response_data
```

.....

```
AttributeError: dict object has no attribute _meta
```

How I can fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django JSON:: 'dict' object has no attribute '\_meta'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061068/django-json-dict-object-has-no-attribute-meta)

Comment: i try do like in that post but error dosen't hide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serialize expect queryset as second argument - and you are passing the list of dicts; docstring:

```
def serialize(format, queryset, **options):
    """
    Serialize a queryset (or any iterator that returns database objects) using
    a certain serializer.
    """
    ...
```

Basically your data is almost serialized. Call simple `json.dumps()`;

Happy codding.

Comment: ty for your time!

Comment: Alternatively you can use JsonResponse: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects This will be probably cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

```
Maybe you want this:
def someUrlFunc(request):
  # ....do some business...
  objs = SomeModel.objects.all().values()
  # you don't need to do this anymore
  # response = serializers.serialize('json', objs, ensure_ascii=False) 
  # just return the values as string
  response = str(list(result)) 
return HttpResponse(response)
```

Update:
Also, you can try this:

```
import json
def someUrlFunc(request):
  objs = SomeModel.objects.all().values()
  response = json.dumps(list(result)) 
return HttpResponse(response)
```