# Json in views.py

Tags: jquery, django, json

I am developing a user interface with Django. I have performed some operations in the views.py. and i have retrieved values which looks like this.

`results = [{'start_time': '23:51:58', 'id_start_time': datetime.time(23, 51, 58)}, {'start_time': '23:59:04', 'id_start_time': datetime.time(23, 59, 4)}]`

i am trying to save this into a json object, to be transferred back to the HTML page, where i have JQuery syntax to perform operations on these values, but for some reason its not working.
The syntax i used is,

import json

```
json_var = json.dumps(results)
```

i have also used syntax of,

```
variable_result = simplejson.dumps(results)
```

But both of them does not seem to work or i may not have understood the logic of how it works. If the syntax is correct, can u please tell me how to view those stored objects.
If the syntax is not correct, can someone please tell me how it should work with a perfect code.

Comment: If you use `return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(results), mimetype="application/json")` to send the data, then it is the correct syntax. How are you parsing this on the client side?

Comment: hi can you please this link: where i have explained much more detailed manner : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860183/dynamic-jquery-view-in-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TypeError: datetime.time(23, 51, 58) is not JSON serializable
```

Serialize/Stringify the datetime object first before using `json.dumps` or `simplejson.dumps`. Python's integrated json serializer can not work with datetime "types", just with built-in types like `int`, `float`, `str`, etc..

Comment: thank you. it is working. the error u have told me is the same. Once i converted it into string, i met the desired functionality

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.core import serializers

json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")
response =  json_serializer.serialize(list, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2, use_natural_keys=True)
return HttpResponse(response, mimetype="application/json")
```

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11470298/513101) or [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#id2)