# what's the alternative solution of tornado's "write" in django?

Tags: python, django, web, tornado

I am using django 1.4. I am moving codes from tornado to django. There is `self.write()` at the end of a `class`. What 's the alternative solution to `self.write()`？ HttpResponse? There is only one template page
so Do I need to response to other page? can I just call response？ or render_to_response to the template page again to wrape data to the page? Is `write()` same with `HttpResponse()`? 
Hey, guys. there are many "?" above, But I only have one problem. An alternative solution of tornado's "write()" in django.
thx for ur time.

The code in tornado looks like:

```
class DataHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    ...
    val = ...
    self.write(val)
```

Maybe in django?

```
def DataHandler(request):
    ...
    val = ...
    return HttpResponse(val)
```

Is that clear about my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpResponse` is typically used if you wish to return non-template responses.

To render templates, use `render` from `django.shortcuts`, for example:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def some_handler(request):
    context_for_template = {}
    return render(request, 'template_name.html', context_for_template)
```

From Tornado's documentation, [`write`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.write) seems to be able to automatically convert a dictionary to JSON. HttpResponse does not do that by default, you should look at [Creating a JSON response using Django and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428092/creating-a-json-response-using-django-and-python) if it is part of your use case.

Comment: I am not gonna to return data to a template. I wish it can be return data to ajax. @Victor Neo "write()" also not return data to template, right?

Comment: If you wish to return data to an Ajax request, then the link I gave on "JSON response using Django" will cover that use case, which uses a combination of HttpResponse and Python's json library.

Answer (score 1):

the [HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#a-simple-view) module

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```