# Django not retrurning response to ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I cannot get a response from server.. my ajax request from html hit the view in django and django returns an response, but callback function not receiving anything... Where is the problem? Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                type: "GET", // GET or POST
                url: "djuka/", // the file to call
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(response) { // on success..
                    alert("aaaa");
                }
            });
```

and view:

```
def djuka(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    print "-->YES"
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message' : 'awesome'},ensure_ascii=False), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

print "-->YES" is executed but alert("aaaa") is never called.....

Comment: Use error callback and check message. BTW, check your console. What about setting correct content type in server response?

Comment: You have a syntax error in the dictionary you are passing inside json.dumps

Comment: Please dont be mad :) but i dont understand you :) Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the print statement. It's making the response invalid JSON.

Comment: Check out A. Wolff's suggestions in the comment. You can debug this by using the browser's console and the $.ajax error call back.

Comment: Sorry i didnt see that answer :)

Comment: I am new in ajax... so did you mean something like this: error: function(xhr, error){
                        alert("aaa");
                        console.debug(xhr);
                        console.debug(error);
                    }

Comment: Yes, that should give you some useful messages... Or, lack of messages indicates something too. What happens when you go to the django URL in your browser?

Comment: Hm, when i go directly to that link i get {"message": "awesome"} but i dont get response to ajax....

Comment: Anyone? :) I am trying whole day and nothing :)

Comment: I think you need to set the mime type to application/json. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428092/creating-a-json-response-using-django-and-python