# JSON data with Django

Tags: jquery, django, json, post

I'm setting up a rating system using the JRating plug-in for JQuery. I have all the front-end stuff working correctly, and am struggling to store the data in my database.

Through what I have researched, it seems the best way to approach storing the data with this jquery plugin using Django is to post a JSON object. Unfortunately, (and fortunately!) I am a complete newbie with JSON.

The post I found with the most relevant information can be found here: [Creating a JSON response using Django and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428092/creating-a-json-response-using-django-and-python/12865351#12865351)

For simplicity sake, I'll show a generic, hard-coded JSON object that I am trying to pass to a django view to store in my database. I currently have this object working and am able to reference it on the page.

```
<!-- jquery in template -->
var testJSON = [
    { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },
    { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },
    { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName": "Jones" }
];

$.post('/blogsearch/setrating/', {"testJSON":testJSON}, function(msg)
{
    if(msg.error == "yes"){console.log('Error Found: '+ msg.errorMsg);}
});
```

And then, in my Django view, for this question I will just do something simple. If I could get the data to return in my view, I would be good to go on the rest.

```
#views.py
def setrating(request):
    response_data = {}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

I am open to any suggestions, including totally reworking how I'm passing the JSON data to be used in my django view.

Comment: Exactly what bit are you having trouble with? JS or Python?

Comment: I'm having trouble with the JS. If I could get the data to return in my view (in this example, through a simple HttpResponse), I would be good to go on the rest. Thanks.

Comment: looking at the console log, it looks like it is trying to pass the JSON object in the Post, but is getting a 403 permission error.    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (FORBIDDEN)  With the post, does it need a CSRF token passed along with the JSON request somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax) on how to include a CSRF token with the Ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [standard Python library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) for deserializing the JSON data, and simply use the [Django model API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api) to create and save your object:

```
import json
import models.Mymodel
data = json.loads(request.POST['testJSON'])
for elem in data:
    m = MyModel(elem)
    m.save()
```

For the JS side, look for [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to submit JSON requests.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the csrf, and I was getting a 403 error when passing the JSON object.

I included the code from [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) in the main js file, and I needed to include {% csrf_token %} on the origin html page.