# Django Activity Feed (Feedly Integration?)

Tags: django, tastypie, feed, django-aggregation

I have built a simple Django photo app. Users can upload photos, follow other users and like photos. To handle relationships amongst the users (following & unfollowing) I use a package called [django-relationships](https://github.com/coleifer/django-relationships) by coleifer. It's a great package and very simple to use.

Everything works as it should. I currently have a working activity feed.

I filter the feed into two sections: Following (all the activities from the users that I follow) & You (all the activities that happened to me). I've posted two pictures below from my iOS app that uses my Django photo app as it's back-end:

[image]
[image]

What I would like to do is add aggregation to the Following Feed. As you can see, user alexperri has liked  5 shots. I would like to aggregate all these items into one line. I don't need to add aggregation for the "You" feed since I would like to see each individual action happening to me. However for the Following feed, it makes sense to add aggregation. There are several applications that do aggregation very well. Fashionlista, Pinterest & Instagram do this well. Here is an example from Instagram to show what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

In the example above, you can see the following feed and that lovetoronto liked 5 photos. I started to play around with the Instagram following feed to see how it works. The Instagram following feed shows a maximum of 35 activity entries and each entry can have a maximum of 5 activities of that action type. "lovetoronto liked 5 photos" is one activity entry and it shows the latest 5 pictures that he liked. Since lovetoronto performed the latest action, he is at the top.

I would like to achieve the same setup.

Here is my current model setup:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Photographer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True
    likes = models.ManyToManyField('Photo', through = 'Likes', 
                                   related_name = 'likedby', blank = True)

class Photo(models.Model):
    photographer = models.ForeignKey(Photographer, related_name = 'shot_owner')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Likes(models.Model):
    liked_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    photographer = models.ForeignKey(Photographer, related_name = 'liked_by')
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, null=True)

class Activity(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(Photographer, related_name = 'actor')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Photographer, related_name = 'receiver')
    action = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Photo, null=True, blank=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Every time a 'Like' object is created, I create an Activity object as well, the actor being the person who did the action, the receiver being the person who the action was done to, the action (in this case a string, 'liked'), post (the photo) and the time being the creation of the activity object.

I use django-tastypie to get and create 'Like' & 'Activity' objects.

**api.py**

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource, ALL, ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
from tastypie.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from tastypie.authorization import DjangoAuthorization, Authorization
from photoapp.photodb.models import *
from tastypie.serializers import Serializer
from relationships.utils import positive_filter
from relationships.models import Relationship
from relationships.models import RelationshipStatus

class LikeResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(BasicUserResource, 'user', full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Photographer.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['put']
        resource_name = 'like'
        fields = ['user']
        default_format = 'application/json'
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
        always_return_data = True
        include_resource_uri = False

        def hydrate(self, bundle):
            shot = Photo.objects.all().get(id = bundle.data['photo id'])
            user = Photographer.objects.all().get(user = bundle.request.user)
            if(bundle.obj.likes.filter(id = bundle.data['photo id']).exists()):
                Likes.objects.all().filter(photographer=user).filter(photo=shot).delete()

                Activity.objects.filter(actor__user = bundle.request.user,
                    post = shot, action = 'liked').delete()

            else:
                like = Likes(photographer = user, photo=shot)
                like.save()
                user_doing_the_liking = User.objects.get(
                    username=bundle.request.user.username)
                user = Photographer.objects.all().get(user = bundle.request.user)
                user_getting_liked = shot.photographer.user
                photographer_getting_liked = shot.photographer
                newActivity = Activity()
                newActivity.actor = user
                newActivity.receiver = photographer_getting_liked
                newActivity.action = 'liked'
                newActivity.post = shot
                newActivity.save()

    return bundle 

class FollowingFeed(ModelResource):
    actor = fields.ForeignKey(BasicPhotographerResource, 'actor', full=True)
    receiver = fields.ForeignKey(BasicPhotographerResource, 'receiver', full=True)
    post = fields.ForeignKey(BasicPostResource, attribute = 'post', full=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Activity.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        resource_name = 'following-feed'
        fields = ['actor', 'receiver', 'action', 'post', 'id', 'time']
        default_format = "application/json"
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
        always_return_data = True
        include_resource_uri = False

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        return super(FollowingFeed, self).get_object_list(request)\
            .filter(actor__user__in = request.user.relationships.following())\
            .exclude(receiver__user = request.user)\
            .exclude(actor__user = request.user).order_by('-time')
```

How can I modify the FollowingFeed resource in such a way that it will aggregate the activity objects? I came across the [Feedly](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Feedly) project. How can I use it with my current setup?

Comment: Do you need to group by `action` as well? Is there any other action type besides `liked`?

Comment: @mariodev thanks for the quick reply. Yes, I would like to group by the user and then the actions they did. Also there are other actions as well. There is following, commenting, and mentioning. That's pretty much it. So instead of the feed showing  each of alexperri's like activities, I would like to aggregate them. "Alexperri liked 5 photos" (Showing the latest 5 pictures in the last hour...even if Alexperri liked more than 5 picture in the last hour, I just want to show the latest 5).

Comment: @mariodev, if alexperri liked 10 pictures and alexperri followed bob and kyle in the last hour. I would like to sort by which action was done the latest. So if the latest action that alexperri made was a "like" and if he was the the latest person of all the people I follow who made an action, I would check the last 100 activities from all the people I follow , grab the latest 5 like actions from alexperri in that list and aggregate it (alexperri liked 5 photos). Then I would check to see who the next person of the people I follow made the second latest action. Run the same logic. etc...

Comment: So then how the rest of the action works.. in case of following, do you list latest followed users? What do you list in case of each action type? Seems to me that the `Activity` table is used only for likes..

Comment: @mariodev check out the LikeResource, where I make newActivity = Activity(). I do the same thing for the FollowResource, CommentResource and MentioningResource. I just didn't add those resources into the question since the question would be too large. I wanted to make the question simple. So for example, in the MentioningResource, I carry out the logic required for mentioning and then do newActivity = Activity(). newActivity.action would be 'mention'. NewActivity receiver = user_being_mentioned. newActivity.post= shot. newActivity.save() Does this make sense? let me know if I am not clear

Comment: @noahandthewhale Nice project you have there. I'm working on an app with a Django backend too. Do you use any library for accessing the API? Any recommendations?

Comment: @webjunkie hey! I use primarily python's json module. Using json.loads and json.dumps and encasing it with the HttpResponse. Here, this will help you. Take a look at the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428092/creating-a-json-response-using-django-and-python. If you need any help just tweet at me [at]riegiegodwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want to do any database level aggregation, because you presumably want to show the individual details as well as the counts e.g. "X like 5 photos" and show the 5 photos. Aggregation, by definition, will exclude the individual data.

Instead, you should do the grouping and sorting in Python code (or Javascript since I think you're using an HTTP API, but I would prefer a server side API that had things already organised).

[itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) might help. I think you need to group by (user and action), and then sort by the timestamp of the first item in each group, so that you might see "Joe liked 5 photos", "Anne posted 2 photos", "Joe posted a photo", "Claire liked 3 photos" etc.

Answer (score 1):

In your feed resource, you are already overriding get_object_list, I would suggest to change the logic to perform a raw query for aggregation logic.

```
def get_object_list(self, request):
        query = "Your aggregation query logic here"
        feed_model = self._meta.object_class
        return feed_model.objects.raw(query)
```

This should do what is required. However, you need to think of your query logic. Let me know if you face any other problem.

Thanks!

Comment: @Rahual Tanwani, thanks for the quick response, it's the query logic that has me scratching my head, that's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to modify the Activity table to store grouped activities. When a new action happens, check for existing ones of the same type and either edit the record to make it 'grouped', or add a new record. You could add ManyToMany relationships to all potential table that contain related records, or just store the data in a json field that contains enough information to render the activity in the feed without making queries to other table objects.

If it's too resource intensive, you can queue the adding/editing of new activities. You're probably better off keeping the activity table just a straight feed that doesn't require any processing when rendered. It's not the easiest solution to implement, but I think that in the long run it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Set the aggregation time, for example do you want to aggregate all “likes” within a 10 minute period or for the past 24 hours?

Then you can filter your object by this time frame.

Then you can apply grouping using the .values(‘model__field’) method. Django generates sql that contains ‘GROUP BY'

And then finally add an aggregation limit so that when the number of likes is over this limit you display the aggregated view rather than the single activity view.

Example below (pseudo, not actual):

```
if (activity.object.filter(time__gt=yourlowertime, time__lt=youruppertime).values(‘activity__action').count() > aggregation_limit) :
     # show aggregated view
else:
     # show normal view
```