# How to get a HTTPRequest JSON response without using any kind of template?

Tags: ajax, django, json, httprequest

I am new to Django but i am advanced programmer in other frameworks.

*What i intend to do:*

Press a form button, triggering Javascript that fires a Ajax request which is processed by a Django View (creates a file) that return plain simple JSON data (the name of the file) - and that is appended as a link to a DOM-Element named 'downloads'.

*What i achieved so far instead:*

Press the button, triggering js that fires a ajax request which is process by a Django view (creates a file) that return the whole page appended as a duplicate to the DOM-Element named 'downloads' (instead of simple JSON data).

here is the extracted code from the corresponding Django view:

```
context = {
    'filename': filename
}
data['filename'] = render_to_string(current_app+'/json_download_link.html', context)
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

I tried several variants (like https://stackoverflow.com/a/2428119/850547), with and without RequestContext object; different rendering strats.. i am out of ideas now..

It seems to me that there is NO possibility to make ajax requests without using a template in the response.. :-/ (but i hope i am wrong)
But even then: Why is Django return the main template (with full DOM) that i have NOT passed to the context...
I just want JSON data - not more!

I hope my problem is understandable... if you need more informations let me know and i will add them.

EDIT:

for the upcoming questions - json_download_link.html looks like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'foobar:download' customer filename %}">Download</a>
```

But i don't even want to use that!

corresponding jquery:

```
    $.post(url, form_data)
    .done(function(result){
        $('#downloads').append('<a href="'+baseUrl+'/download/'+result['filename']+'" title="download"> Download CSV</a>')
    })
```

Comment: Seems like your AJAX request calls other snippet of code. It is possible to serve JSON from Django view and your code looks good.

Comment: What does the output of render_to_string(current_app+'/json_download_link.html'...) look like?

Comment: i added the info, please see my EDIT above

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question. Of course you can make an Ajax request without using a template. If you don't want to use a template, don't use a template. If you just want to return JSON, then do that.

Without having any details of what's going wrong, I would imagine that your Ajax request is not hitting the view you think it is, but is going to the original full-page view. Try adding some logging in the view to see what's going on.

Comment: the correct view is processed, i checked it via test outputs.

when i do sth. like:

return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'foo':'bar'}), content_type="application/json")

the result is the same: the full DOM will be duplicated and appended where only the filename link should be appended..

Comment: Sorry, that is not possible. It is not coming from the view you have above, that's all I can say. Django would not magically recreate your whole page without being told to.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to return the full template. You can return parts of template and render/append them at the frontend.

A template can be as small as you want. For example this is a template:

```
name.html
<p>My name is {{name}}</p>
```

You can return only this template with `json.dumps()` and append it on the front end.

What is your `json_download_link.html`?

assuming example.csv is string

```
data ={}
data['filename'] = u'example.csv'
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: i added the info, please see my EDIT above

Comment: Ok. i dont get it.. what do you want your output to be?

Comment: plain JSON:
{"filename": "example.csv"}

Comment: concerning your EDIT: yes, this is what i already tried and what i want... but in the response full DOM will be duplicated and appended.. there is something wrong..

Comment: yeah i guess, check the response of the view and see what its returning

Comment: ... it is the full DOM