# json dump with dict as value

Tags: python, django, json, dictionary

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428092/creating-a-json-response-using-django-and-python) clearly explains how to send a response using json and python dicts. The example however uses **String** as the value type in this dict. How would one do this with dict as value type? That is a dict with with dict as a value.

Comment: I wasn't specific enough. The specific type of dict I was referring to had a tuple as a key: json.dumps({'foo': {('bar','baz'): 42}}) results in "TypeError: keys must be a string"

Comment: A Key of dictionary cannot be tuple `('bar', 'baz')` is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify adityasdarma1's comment: this is not a limitation of Python or Django, but of JSON. In JSON, object keys must always be strings. There is no "tuple" type in JSON or JavaScript anyway; and arrays can't be keys because they are mutable. (In Python, tuples *can* be dict keys, but lists can't.)

I'm not sure why you would need that, though. You can either concatenate the values in some way to make a string key - eg `"bar-baz"` - or alternatively you might need a more complex nested structure, with `bar` as the key of the outer dict and `baz` as an inner one. Without seeing your full data structure, it's hard to advise further.

Answer (score 1):

By giving it a dict with a dict as a value type.

```
>>> json.dumps({'foo': {'bar': 42}})
'{"foo": {"bar": 42}}'
```