# Django backwards relation

Tags: python, django

I am setting up webservices for an application and I have the following models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    ...
class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    ...
```

The relation is One to Many (1 Parent, many Children)

Now, I would like to get all the Parent objects with its particular Child and send it as a JSON Request.

Is it possible to do so without having to first get all the "Childs" and iterate through them looking for the ones related to the particular parent?

I think that would be extremely inefficient for really large databases, plus the "Childs" won't be repeated in other "Parents"

Thank you very much

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Every relationship in Django automatically gets its reverse relation added to the model. In the case of a `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField` that relation contains several objects. In that case, the default attribute name is set to `<model>_set`, so in this case `child_set`. This is a manager and can be used as such, so e.g. to iterate over all children:

```
for child in parent.child_set.all():
    do_something()
```

You can also specify the attribute name used for the reverse relation using the `related_name` attribute:

```
class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')

for child in parent.children.filter(some_field=True):
    do_something()
```

Read more in the documentation on [following relations backwards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) and [how are backward relationships possible](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#how-are-the-backward-relationships-possible).

Answer (score 2):

Why would you need to iterate? Even if Django didn't provide you with a special backwards syntax, you could always do this:

```
Child.objects.filter(parent=my_parent)
```

but as a cursory Google for the title of your question would have shown, there is a special syntax for backwards relations:

```
my_parent.child_set.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in django you can use:

```
parentInstance.child_set.all()
```

where `parentInstance` is one particular parent in your `Parent` database. That will return all of the Child objects associated with it in an efficient manner. To make it a JSON response, you can try something like this:

```
import json

from django.http import HttpResponse

response_data = {}
response_data[str(parentInstance)] = parentInstance.child_set.all()
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json"
```

adopted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428092/creating-a-json-response-using-django-and-python).