# Django URL Routing Issue

Tags: python, django

Very new to Django, so I apologize as I'm sure this has an easy answer.

I have a PHP background, and so I guessing that I am trying to force a structure I am used to, and not one that is native in Django.

Here is my **Project's `urls.py`**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('pm.urls', namespace='pm')),
)
```

Here is my **App's `urls.py`**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from pm import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^label/add/$', views.add_label, name='label_add'),
)
```

I am doing an AJAX Post request to /label/add/, but it's coming back with a 500 error.

This is the **`views.py`**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from pm.models import Label
import json

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    labels_list = Label.objects.order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'pm/index.html', {
        'labels' : labels_list
    })


""" Labels """
def add_label(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        response = {
            'success': True
       }
    else:
        response = {
            'success': False,
            'error': "Invalid request"
        }

    return json.dumps(response)
```

Any advise or references would be great.

---

**UPDATE**

Here's the first couple of lines from the traceback I am getting:

```
AttributeError at /label/add/
'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: put `DEBUG = True` to your settings and then check the response for your ajax request with Firebug or similar tool to see the full traceback of the error. I think the problem is that you've to return `HttpResponse`, not just serialized json.

Comment: yup, you've the problem I described - your `view` returns just string, but you have to return `HttpResponse` object

Comment: I want to return just serialized JSON, how do I make that happen?

Comment: idk, probably something like `return HttpReponse(json.dumps(response),mimetype='application/json')`

Comment: Thank you -- if you put that as the answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I referenced this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428092/creating-a-json-response-using-django-and-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to return `HttpResponse` instead of string:

```
return HttpReponse(json.dumps(response), content_type='application/json')
```