# Django: how to pass json data as url to template for table sort and search

Tags: json, django, twitter-bootstrap

I like bootstrap and I am trying to add a bootstrap sortable & searchable table(s) to my django site. like on  [http://wenzhixin.net.cn/](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#sort-table)

the example code looks fairly strait forward. except that i cannot figure out the very first part `data-url="data1.json"`

```
<table data-url="data1.json" data-height="299" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id" data-align="right" data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
            <th data-field="name" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
            <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I am able to create Json data bassed on this Stackoverflow [Creating a JSON response using Django and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428092/creating-a-json-response-using-django-and-python) but I cannot figure out how to format it as a url that django/table can access.

Comment: You can create new view returned a HttpResponse containing your json results. To create json, you can dump your data as a dictionary and dump it with json built in module in python. or django built in serializer from your model queryset.