# django HttpResponse in json

Tags: python, json, django, httpresponse

I have a view :

```
def add_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        files = request.FILES.getlist("file")
        response_data = {}

        for file in files:
            my_model = MyModel()
            my_model.my_file = file
            my_model.save()
            id_info = my_model.id
            response_data.append(id_info)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

Here lets say if there are 5 files then I want to send the id of 5 file in response through json. Here its saying local variable response_data referenced before assignment.

I want to send the id of all 5 files. How to do this ?

Comment: Because you delcare `response_data` inside of the `for` loop

Comment: Are you sure this is your exact code? This code would raise errors

Comment: its response_data instead of response_date in top

Comment: Even so, a dictionary does not have an append method.

Comment: your dict {} should be replaced with list []

Comment: If I wish to use dictionary then ?

Comment: Then you will need a key and value to store... like response_data['THE_KEY'] = id_info

Comment: after doing that it says 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_header'

Comment: can you verify that your Django version? Is it 1.7+
IF so change HttpResponse to JsonResponse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428092/creating-a-json-response-using-django-and-python/24411716#24411716

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you are defining `response_data = {}` inside the `if` and your `return response` is outside, because that you are getting `response_data referenced before assignment` error.

Second, a dict has not `append()` method. You should declare your `responde_data` as a list

```
def add_view(request):
    response_data = []
    if request.method == "POST":

        files = request.FILES.getlist("file")


        for file in files:
            my_model = MyModel()
            my_model.my_file = file
            my_model.save()
            id_info = my_model.id
            response_data.append(id_info)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: what if I use dict. Using list will give me data in correct json format ?

Comment: @gamer python list are json serializable, but is you want a dict, just wrapp it using {}  `json.dumps({'response_data':response_data})`