# How return json in django for bootstrap table

Tags: json, django, bootstrap-table

How return json from queryset - **A.objects.all()** to bootstrap table (http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html):

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-url="data" data-cache="false" data-height="299">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
            <th data-field="name">Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**in views:**

```
data = serializers.serialize("json", A.objects.all())
return render(request, 'a.html', {'data': data})
```

Comment: why do you want to return a json here? You can directly send you data without serializing it and use template tags to display them in your page

Answer (score 3):

There is 2 modes : server or client

For server mode:

in utils.py :

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
import json
def serialize_bootstraptable(queryset):
    json_data = serialize('json', queryset)
    json_final = {"total": queryset.count(), "rows": []}
    data = json.loads(json_data)
    for item in data:
        del item["model"]
        item["fields"].update({"id": item["pk"]})
        item = item["fields"]
        json_final['rows'].append(item)
    return json_final
```

in views.py :

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
json_send = serialize_bootstraptable(Model.objects.all())
return JsonResponse(json_send, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django `JsonResponse`.
See the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects).

You would do something like this:

```
def my_json_view(request):
    context = {'foo': bar}
    return JsonResponse(context)
```

See also this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428092/creating-a-json-response-using-django-and-python).

Hope this helps ! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

In views:

```
def test(request):
    data = A.objects.all().values()
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'data': data})
```

In template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#table').bootstrapTable({
           data:{{data|safe}}
        });    
    });
</script>

<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
            <th data-field="name">Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```