# Working with JSON and Django

Tags: json, django, django-models

I am new to Python and Django. I am an IT professional that deploys software that monitors computers. The api outputs to JSON. I want to create a Django app that reads the api and outputs the data to an html page. Where do I get started? I think the idea is to write the JSON feed to a Django model. Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Here's a simple single file to extract the JSON data:

```
import urllib2
import json

def printResults(data):
    theJSON = json.loads(data)
    for i in theJSON[""]


def main():
    urlData = ""

    webUrl = urllib2.urlopen(urlData)
    if (webUrl.getcode() == 200):
        data = webUrl.read()
        printResults(data)
    else:
        print "Received error"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: When you say _The api outputs to JSON_ it is like http://.../api/report and it returns a json?

Comment: Check [django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and also check [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) and an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428092/creating-a-json-response-using-django-and-python/24411716#24411716)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an URL returning a json as response, you could try this:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://....'  # Your api url

response = requests.get(url)
json_response = response.json()
```

Now `json_response` is a `list` containing `dicts`. Let's suppose you have this structure:

```
[
  {
     'code': ABC,
     'avg': 14.5,
     'max': 30
  },
  {
     'code': XYZ,
     'avg': 11.6,
     'max': 21
  },
  ...
]
```

You can iterate over the list and take every dict into a model.

```
from yourmodels import CurrentModel

    ...
    for obj in json_response:
        cm = CurrentModel()
        cm.avg = obj['avg']
        cm.max = obj['max']
        cm.code = obj['code']
        cm.save()
```

Or you could use a [bulk method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create), but keep in mind that **`bulk_create` does not trigger `save` method.**

Comment: How would I turn that into a model? I think that's not what I'm understanding.