# Creating UTF-8 JsonResponse in Django

Tags: json, django, utf-8

Is there any simple way to override `DjangoJSONEncoder.ensure_ascii` and set it to `False` or output non-ascii text in `django.http.JsonResponse` in any other way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As of Django 1.9 you can configure `JSONResponse` to disable the `ensure_ascii` switch, by passing in a value for the [`json_dumps_params` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects):

```
return JsonResponse(response_data, safe=False, json_dumps_params={'ensure_ascii': False})
```

With `ensure_ascii=False`, `json.dumps()` outputs UTF-8 data for non-ASCII codepoints.

You could subclass `JsonResponse` to make it the default unless set differently:

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse

class UTF8JsonResponse(JsonResponse):
    def __init__(self, *args, json_dumps_params=None, **kwargs):
        json_dumps_params = {"ensure_ascii": False, **(json_dumps_params or {})}
        super().__init__(*args, json_dumps_params=json_dumps_params, **kwargs)
```

then use that throughout instead of JsonResponse.

At the extreme end, you could monkey-patch the class to set `ensure_ascii` to `False` by default; put the following in a suitable module of your Django app (say, in a file named `patches.py`):

```
import logging
from functools import wraps
from django.http.response import JsonResponse

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def patch_jsonresponse_disable_ensure_ascii():
    if getattr(JsonResponse, '_utf8_patched', False):
        # Already patched. Add warning in logs with stack to see what location
        # is trying to patch this a second time.
        logger.warning("JSONResponse UTF8 patch already applied", stack_info=True)
        return

    logger.debug("Patching JSONResponse to disable ensure_ascii")
    orig_init = JsonResponse.__init__

    @wraps(orig_init)
    def utf8_init(self, *args, json_dumps_params=None, **kwargs):
        json_dumps_params = {"ensure_ascii": False, **(json_dumps_params or {})}
        orig_init(self, *args, json_dumps_params=json_dumps_params, **kwargs)

    JsonResponse.__init__ = utf8_init
    JsonResponse._utf8_patched = True  # to prevent accidental re-patching
```

then import `patch_jsonresponse_disable_ensure_ascii` into your Django settings file and call it based on your desired config:

```
from yourapp.patches import patch_jsonresponse_disable_ensure_ascii

JSON_RESPONSES_UTF8 = True

if JSON_RESPONSES_UTF8:
    patch_jsonresponse_disable_ensure_ascii()
```

Comment: Is there any setting item to set that to False golbally instead of put that in every JsonResponse?

Comment: @Jcyrss: expanded my answer to give you some more gradations, including monkeypatching Django itself to always set the flag to false.

Answer (score 11):

EDIT:

Or if you tend to the utf-8 format, use instead of Django's JsonResponse():

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data, ensure_ascii=False),
         content_type="application/json")
```

or

```
return JsonResponse(json.dumps(response_data, ensure_ascii=False), safe=False)
```

more about the `safe=False` [HERE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

---

OLD:

You don't have to whatever alter.

Although Django creates JSON data in ASCII (from UTF-8), Javascript will automatically decode it back to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I prefer readability over slightly better backward compatibility that I don't need at all in my case. Also, UTF-8 is recommended in RFC 7159.

Comment: `JsonResponse(json.dumps(response_data, ensure_ascii=False), ...)` **doesn't work** as this **double-encodes the data**. There is no point in s etting `safe=False` in that case *either*, as that flag applies to what is accepted when encoding the data to JSON. Since you already encoded all objects to a JSON string, there are no 'unsafe' objects to encode anymore.

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.http import JsonResponse


class MyJsonResponse(JsonResponse):
    def __init__(self, data, encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder, safe=True, **kwargs):
        json_dumps_params = dict(ensure_ascii=False)
        super().__init__(data, encoder, safe, json_dumps_params, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This could be improved by allowing for `json_dumps_params` to be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any better way yet than to utilize an already installed REST Framework:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import INITIATOR_TYPES

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, ))
def initiator_types(request):
    data = {t[0]: str(t[1]) for t in INITIATOR_TYPES}
    return Response(data)
```

But I don't really like it. It's much more complicated than `JsonResponse`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24411716/854477

Comment: You should put it as part of your original question.

Comment: It's a solution that I decided to share and simultaneously try searching for a better one.