# i am using django as a backend to flutter

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dart, django-rest-framework

when i get data from API Arabix words doesn't show and it show like this [image]

is this from flutter or Django Restframework?

flutter request
'''
final url = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000');

```
  final data =  await http.get(url);
  final flats = json.decode(data.body) as List<dynamic>;
  if(flats==null) {
    return;
  }
```

print(flats)

'''

Comment: Could you post your Django API code?

Comment: i think the Django api code is right because i test the api with postman and it show the words correct

Comment: Make sure you're using UTF-8 encoding. You can use `curl` to help narrow down whether the issue is on the backend or client side.

Comment: i think this is Encoding Error. Confirm server side [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798703/creating-utf-8-jsonresponse-in-django)

Comment: i use restframework classes

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use dio instead of http.