# Python-problems with parsing list in JSON Format

Tags: python, json

I'm using python 2.7 to parse value in JSON format
there is my script:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
import os
import pickle
d=OrderedDict([(3215, False), (3216, False), (8004, False), (8002, False),         (3589, False), (3753, False), (3752, True), (3755, False), (3754, False)]))
json_format = json.dumps(d.items())
Fichier =open('C:\\Users\\Dev\\Desktop\\file\\json.json','wb')
pickle.dump(json_format,Fichier)
Fichier =open('C:\\Users\\Dev\\Desktop\\file\\json.json','rb')
final_result_from_fichier = pickle.load(Fichier)
```

but after executing this script i found some external character the json file
there is the output of my script :

```
S'[[3215, false], [3216, false], [8004, false], [8002, false], [3589, false], [3753, false], [3752, True], [3755, false], [3754, false]]'p0
```

What can I do ?

Comment: Why are you using `pickle.load()` on a JSON data file?

Answer (score 2):

You double-encoded the dictionary to JSON, then to pickle, in the file:

```
json_format = json.dumps(d.items())
Fichier =open('C:\\Users\\Dev\\Desktop\\file\\json.json','wb')
pickle.dump(json_format,Fichier)
```

That's writing the `json_format` *string* to the open file object, as Pickle encoded data. Even if you corrected this, the JSON format is **not** a Python pickle format. You can't load JSON with the `pickle` module. Just use `json.load()` to do so.

Use *just* `json.dump()` with the dictionary:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\Dev\\Desktop\\file\\json.json', 'wb') as Fichier:
    json.dump(d, Fichier)
```

if you want a JSON object (key-value pairs), or use `d.items()` if you need a JSON array containing nested arrays each with a key and a value:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\Dev\\Desktop\\file\\json.json', 'wb') as Fichier:
    json.dump(d.items(), Fichier)
```

I opened the files as a context manager to ensure it is closed again after the write operation completes.

You can load the JSON object (first snippet) back into an OrderedDict with:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\Dev\\Desktop\\file\\json.json','rb') as Fichier:
    final_result_from_fischier = json.load(Fichier, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

Comment: @bader: ah, sorry, my apologies. I have corrected the answer; I accidentally copied your `pickle` lines instead of correcting them to `json.dump` and `json.load` calls. Mea Culpa!

Comment: it is worked it is worked thanks, thanks very much :)

Comment: i have other question why i don' find the same forma like the list d ?? when i open the file i find:{"3215": false, "3216": false, "8004": false, "8002": false}

Comment: Not sure what you are asking?

Comment: when i open the file i find :{"3215": false, "3216": false, "8004": false, "8002": false} why didn't find list like this: [(3215, False), (3216, False), (8004, False), (8002, False)] ???

Comment: @bader: you can't have that; you can have `[[3215, false], [3216, false], [8004, false], [8002, false]]`; just write `d.items()` to the JSON file; the JSON format only supports arrays (square brackets), and booleans are always all-lowercase in JSON. Loading that back into an `OrderedDict` requires that you pass the data you load from the file into a `OrderedDict` call.

Comment: ahhhh i'm so sorry i forgot to copied d.items() ,Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Consider posting a new question post then.

Comment: sorry for this disturbance,but i Have other question :/ Now i want to use this file in template of Django how can i call his directory !! i have been changed the directory of my file in directory of my project,i used <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'json.json' %}">  $(document).ready(function() {
    var myItems;
    $.getJSON('json.json', function(data) {
        myItems = data.items;
        console.log(myItems);
    });
});   doesn't work :/

Comment: @bader: use a JSONResponse in Django: [Creating a JSON response using Django and Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2428092)

Comment: my json file had a dynamic changes,so i want to access directly to his directory and i want to use  setInteval(function,1000) without reload the page HTML

Comment: this is the solution :$.getJSON('/static/json.json',function(data){} thanks :)