# how return json as text file in django rest framework

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

That's a very naive question which means that I don't understand something very basic about how DRF works, but still: 
What is the way get a response from DRF in a form of text file containing json?

I have a ListAPIView:

```
class MyModelJSONView(generics.ListAPIView):
   serializer_class = MySerializer
   queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
```

I guess I should re-write the `get` method of this `ListAPIView` somehow to get a text file (I assume by adding `Content-Disposition` to a response. But how?

Comment: A similar question was asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428092/creating-a-json-response-using-django-and-python).

Comment: You can always save the JSON response to a text file.

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyModelJSONView(generics.ListAPIView):

    def get(self, request):

        filename = 'test.txt'
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        serializer = MySerializer(queryset)
        response = HttpResponse(serializer.data, content_type='text/plain; charset=UTF-8')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = ('attachment; filename={0}'.format(filename))

        return response
```