# Load data from model in view.py Django

Tags: python, django

I just started with Django and Python and I still don't understand it very well. Would it be possible to access all the information stored in **Persons**, showing also **orderstext** and **archivename**, I can't manage to do it :( my idea is to get all the information and save it as JSON, but I'm not getting the info from **orderstext** and **archivename**, it would be great if someone could show me the right way.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    orderstext = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True, )
    order_start = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    order_end = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def default(self):
        return self.orderstext

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'order'



class Archives(models.Model):
    archive_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    archivename = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    deleted = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.archivename 

    @property
    def default(self):
        return self.archivename

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'archives'


class Clients(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Name")
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Lastname")
    archives = models.ForeignKey('Archives', db_column='archive_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name="Archives")
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order', db_column='order_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name="Order")
    coments = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Coments")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'clients'
```

views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

from .models import Clients

def data_json:
    info = list(Clients.objects.all().values())
    response = {'clients': info}
    
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('clients-info/', views.data_json, name='data_json'),
]
```

JSON Response

```
{
  "clients": {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "First",
    "lastname": "Last Name",
    "archive_id": 6,
    "order_id": 3,
    "coments": "No comments"
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `values()`.

Comment: @OMY Without values() I´m getting this error: Object of type Clients is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`annotate`**..[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) the clients queryset with the `orderstext` and `archivename` along side [**`F-expressions`**..[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations) like this:

```
from django.db.models import F

Clients.objects.annotate(
    archivename=F("archives__archivename"), 
    orderstext=F("order__orderstext"),
).values()
```

Although instead of using `values` I highly recommend using something like [**`DRF serializers`**..[DRF-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) to handle serialization of your data.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you'd want to get a certain field data on the `FK` field on each client object, but what you're getting is the `pk` value of `Order` and `Archive` models on each `Client` objects.

```
{
     "clients": {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "First",
          "lastname": "Last Name",
          "archive_id": 6,  # foreign key pk field reference
          "order_id": 3,  # foreign key pk field reference
          "coments": "No comments"
     }
}
```

If I'm correct, then one approach you could use is to change the reference name to reference the fields `orderstext` and `archivename` respectively instead of `order_id` and `archive_id`.

So I wouldn't change anything else but just the two `foreign key` fields on the `Client model`. Updating the reference where `db_column` points:

```
class Clients(models.Model):
     ... 
     archives = models.ForeignKey('Archives', db_column='archivename', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name="Archives")
     order = models.ForeignKey('Order', db_column='orderstext', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name="Order")
     ...
```

You can read more from the doc on [db-column](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#db-column).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I can't change the Models..

Answer (score 1):

There're several answers in this [12-years old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428092/creating-a-json-response-using-django-and-python). I believe more of one might solve your problem.

Below one example of solution:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core.serializers import serialize

from .models import Clients

def data_json(request):
    info = Clients.objects.all()
    response = serialize('json', info)
    
    return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

I recommend you read the documentation about [JSON request and response objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) and [serialization formats](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json).